# "only once did she give way to emotions"

Tags: grammar

"only once did she give way to emotions". Why is "did" used before "she", although it is not an interrogative statement?

Comment: Forgive me fixing your grammar, but it's relevant to the question.

Comment: "Only once did she give way to emotions" is not as idiomatic as either "Only once did she give way to her emotions" or "Only once did she give way to emotion".